# flutter problem : how to remove brackets of list data

Tags: flutter, api, rest, flutter-web, flutter-test

### this is my postman response, In this response I have a "areaOfMentoring" Key In Area of mentoring key i have two data And I want to show both data.

[image]

### but when fetching areaOfMentoring's data then its showing like this

[image]

areaOfMentoring's data is Diabetes and Heart Health Its showing after abhijeet vijayvargiya
There are coming brackets too, so how to show only areaOfMentoring's data without bracket

this is my code for this card

```
Container(
                  clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: (index % 2) == 0
                        ? Color(0xFFC691D3).withOpacity(0.2)
                        : Color(0xFFF6931E).withOpacity(0.2),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        topRight: Radius.circular(10.0),
                        bottomRight: Radius.circular(10.0),
                        topLeft: Radius.circular(10.0),
                        bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10.0)),
                  ),
                  height: 290,
                  width: 160,
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Image.asset(
                        'assets/herogirl.png',
                        height: 154,
                        width: 142,
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 5, 10, 5),
                        child: Text(
                          '${healthHeroesListData[index]['name']}',
                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                          maxLines: 1,
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                            fontSize: 14,
                            color: Color(0xff444444),
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 0),
                        child: Text(
                          '${healthHeroesListData[index]['areaOfMentoring']}',
                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          maxLines: 2,
                          style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                            fontSize: 12,
                            color: (index % 2) == 0
                                ? Color(0xffC691D3)
                                : Color(0xffF6931E),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      ElevatedButton(
                          style: ButtonStyle(
                            backgroundColor: (index % 2) == 0
                                ? MaterialStateProperty.all(Color(0xFFC691D3))
                                : MaterialStateProperty.all(Color(0xFFF6931E)),
                            shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<
                                RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                              RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                                // side: BorderSide(color: Colors.teal, width: 0.0),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) => ApplySession(healthHeroesListData:healthHeroesListData[index])));
                          },
                          child: Text('View Details'))
                    ],
                  ),
                );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are letting dart apply the `toString` method on an array, resulting in showing it as a raw JSON string.

You just need to somehow iterate on your entries or join them:

```
'${healthHeroesListData[index]['areaOfMentoring'].join(', ')}'
```

Answer (score 1):

You have many ways, the most simple is:

```dart
healthHeroesListData[index]['areaOfMentoring'].join(', ') // with comas
healthHeroesListData[index]['areaOfMentoring'].join(' ') // no comas
```